# CakePHP 3.x Event System

Tags: php, cakephp

I can't figure out why the afterSave event in my model is not being triggered. It seems that when I run the save method within the initialize method of the table, the afterSave event isn't triggered.

In my table class:

```
public function initialize(array $config) {
    parent::initialize($config);
    ....
    $this->save($test);
}

public function afterSave($event, $entity, $options) {
    Log::debug('yay the event fired.');
}
```

The item is saved - I've checked that - and I've not implemented anything that would stop the event from propagating. I've tested that the afterSave event is set up correctly because when I save outside of the initialize method - from the controller - it works fine. In 2.x this would have worked fine.

I will admit that even though I've read the whole book on the event system and some I still don't have a complete grasp of it, so I'm probably missing something?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A look at the source code often helps in such cases.

```
public function __construct(array $config = [])
{
    // ...

    $this->initialize($config);
    $this->_eventManager->on($this);

    // ...
}
```

**https://github.com/cakephp/cakephp/blob/3.2.0/src/ORM/Table.php#L282-L283**

As you can see, the `initialize` method is invoked before the table is being registered as an event listener, and therefore your event callback is not being invoked.

So to achieve what you're trying to do there, ie save something when a model is being instantiated/initialized and have the model callbacks invoked, you could use the constructor, or a `Model.initialize` event listener.